# How to get file name from its size property in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i have a scan a particular directory in my web server and listed all the file size as an array and have deleted the one with the largest size using the array_pop() function, how will i get the file name of the remaining array items through the file size

```
    foreach ($name as $value) {
    $sea = @array_search((filesize($name[$ppo])/1024),$size);
    $size[$sea] = $name[$ppo];
    $ppo++;

  }
```

Comment: Instead of storing just sizes store __both__ filename and sizes.

Comment: thanks for the reply, how do i store both filename and size in a single array. i tried to use  foreach ($name as $value) {
  $sea = @array_search($size[$ppo],(filesize($name[$ppo])/1024));
  $size[$sea] = $name[$ppo];
  $ppo++;
} but each it always returned 2 for all the array key of $size array

Comment: Never write your code in a comment. Edit your question.

Comment: Sorry im new here ive edited the question and the code should be properly formatted there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `array_search()`.